# Windows 11: How to open Last active window on taskbar for Chrome

Tags: windows, google-chrome, taskbar

I have multiple Chrome windows open. Every time I go to another application and come back to Chrome by clicking on it in the taskbar or using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, the last created window is opened.

It's very annoying that I need to find the right Chrome window all the time.

I already tried some RegEdit steps someone used to solve this problem in windows 10, but it doesn't work on Windows 11.

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced
```

I created `LastActiveClick` and set it to 1

Any fix for this on Windows 11?

Answer (score 0):

Native Windows 11 does not allow you to ungroup task bar icons. Windows 10 did, but not Windows 11. I have been using Windows 11 for about 21 months and it has always been this way.

Please see:  [Windows 11 Icons](https://www.androidauthority.com/ungroup-icons-taskbar-windows-11-3149488/)

> Windows has changed a lot over the years and has lost some old-school features along the way. Window grouping on the taskbar is a relatively new feature, but Windows used to give you the option to get the old ungroup icon style. But can you do that in Windows 11? Here’s how to ungroup icons on the taskbar in Windows 11 so that you don’t have to downgrade to Windows 10.
>
> To ungroup icons on the taskbar in Windows 11, you'll have to install a third-party program StartAllBack. Click Taskbar in the left navigation pane of the app, and locate the option to ungroup taskbar icons under Tweak behavior and superpowers.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 11 has removed the "Never combine" feature of the taskbar.

You may return this option by installing the
[ExplorerPatcher](https://github.com/valinet/ExplorerPatcher).

After installing the app, it will automatically set the
Taskbar icon alignment to the left and also the icons are set to
"never combine" by default.

Answer (score 0):

In Window 11 23h2,  I faced the opposite problem, in which ungroup icons on the taskbar is enabled,   the only way I can combine/group items in the TB is to choose "when taskbar is full" and even then it hides the labels.  Besides this, you can no longer create a two-level TB, nor a Quick Launch.
[image]

For this,  [ExplorerPatcher.](https://github.com/valinet/ExplorerPatcher) along with [7+taskbar tweaker beta](https://ramensoftware.com/7-taskbar-tweaker) is an answer. With developer Michael Ramen's diligent [help here](https://ramensoftware.com/7-taskbar-tweaker/comment-page-54#comment-14808) I was even able to see each group of individual TB buttons/icons for each one of multiple installations of Firefox Portable  running concurrently (each used for its own generally  purpose and labeled  - via Fire Title ext)..

[image]